# Sending typing indication

Tags: bottender

Is there a way to send a message with the typing indication using only one function call.

Or do I have to turn the typing on during a certain amount of time and then turn it off before sending the message?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to find in the examples folder.
I was searching in the docs but it seems it is not well documented. `the delay and withTyping`

Here the whole example file for referance.

```
const { MessengerBot, withTyping } = require('bottender');
const { createServer } = require('bottender/express');

const bot = new MessengerBot({
  accessToken: '__FILL_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE__',
  appSecret: '__FILL_YOUR_SECRET_HERE__',
});

bot.use(withTyping({ delay: 1000 }));

bot.onEvent(async context => {
 await context.sendText('Hello World');
 await context.sendText('Hello World');
 await context.sendText('Hello World~~~~~~~~~~', { delay: 2000 });
});

const server = createServer(bot);

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('server is running on 5000 port...');
});
```